# Robot ValueError: Cannot represent value as binary

Tags: python, robotframework, winreg

i need help

I have a problem with getting dictionary of registry (name and value)

Robot Framework return this error

ValueError: Cannot represent u'"=f\xd8\u0152\xc4R\xd9\xd4\u2021\xb20\xd0\xf5\xef\x0fx\xbc\x0b\x06' as binary.

i have a function which can get a dictionary of all elements but one data value is "=fØŒÄRÙÔ‡²0Ðõïx¼ and can't read it.

Anybody can help me to handle it

my function

```
def get_info(self):
    system_info = {}
    key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"Software", 0, _winreg.KEY_READ)
    try:
        i = 0
        while 1:
            name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
            system_info[name] = value                         
            i += 1
    except WindowsError as error:
        raise WindowsError(error)
    return system_info
```

P.S. : i don't wanna share specific registry

```
def get_registry_info(self, registry, variable):
    """Gets various infomation in registry.

    :registry: path to the registry
    :variable: variable in registry
    :returns: value of selected variable in registry information
    """
    hkey, register = registry.split("\\",1)
    key = _winreg.OpenKey(getattr(_winreg,hkey),
            register, 0, _winreg.KEY_READ)
    try:
        i = 0
        name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
        i += 1
    except WindowsError:
        print
    value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, variable)
    return value
```

Rado

Comment: Is that the actual, literal error message? It looks odd that it begins with `u'"` (single-quote followed by double quote) but ends with only a single quote.

Comment: this is a value "=fØŒÄRÙÔ‡²0Ðõïx¼ with one single-quote, which is stored in one variable

Comment: function was reworked